# Wider autocomplete suggestions in JTable combobox using glazedlists

Tags: java, jtable, glazedlists

Is there any way that I can make the suggestions box wider without actually changing the width of that jtable column? I want to make the suggestion box wider than the actual jcombobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way is to use the [JComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setPrototypeDisplayValue%28E%29) method; ideally you'd pass in the longest item so that the combobox can set a good default width.

This is briefly touched upon in the [GlazedLists Developer Tutorials](http://publicobject.com/glazedlistsdeveloper/); see "AutoCompleteSupport Screencast" for the walkthrough.

Comment: Thank you very much, i was having trouble with that for weeks.